# When saving data(array of objects) in React.State/ LocalStorage using ReactHooks, facing an error

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, react-hooks

i am looking to save the customer product selection in basket and to avoid the effect of `refesh` of page i am also saving the customer selection to local storage, i am use spread `....prevItems`and using `window.localStorage.setItem`,but  as  prevItems initial value is `null` so it comes up with an error of `TypeError: prevItems is not iterable`, i have tried passing the product,quantity to initial value(to make to iterable afterwards) but the `initialvalue= callback` is present outside the main function  and was unsuccessful.
Not sure what else i can do to overcome this issue.

**Update:1** the below code is now working

```
     let initialvalue = () => {
         = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("user-basket") || "[]");
        };
        
        function App() {
        const [basketItems, setBasketItems] = useState(initialvalue());
    // basketItems will be like[{Product1},{Product2}, and so on...] i.e it will store each product as a new object
     const addBasketitems = (product, quantity) => {
        setBasketItems((prevItems) => {

            if (prevItems === null) {
        const newItems = [prevItems, { ...product, quantity }];
        console.log(newItems);
        window.localStorage.setItem("user-basket", JSON.stringify(newItems));
        console.log(prevItems);
        return newItems;

      } else {
        const newItems = [...prevItems, { ...product, quantity }];
        console.log(newItems);
        window.localStorage.setItem("user-basket", JSON.stringify(newItems));
        console.log(prevItems);
        return newItems;
      }
     });
   }; 
 <Router>
     
          <Switch>
          
            <Route
             path="/"
              exact
              render={(props) => <Home {...props} userData={userData} userstatus={siginalready} addBasketitems={addBasketitems} 
           />}
         </Switch>
 </Router>
```

- initially the below error was coming up when i use `...prevItems`
  [image]
- when i place the `(prevItems==null? {}:prevItems )` to check if it is null then the below error comes up
  [image]

console log showing that i am receiving, `products`, `Quantity` and `PrevItem` is `null.`

[image]

- when adding `newItems = [{ ...(prevItems == null ? {} : prevItems) }, { ...product, quantity }];` it always return two objects in an array
  [image]

Comment: You can do a null check, if `prevItems` is not null, include it. Else don't include it. A way to do that succinctly in the same line would be `...(prevItems || {})`. The parameters will return `prevItems` if it is truthy, or the empty object which is iterable but returns nothing.

Comment: Thanks D.Smith, i have added this (prevItems==null? { }:prevItems ) to check the null condition but now coming up with TypeError: object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator)). i have updated the code and the error above.

Comment: I think it might have to be within another object. Javascript is not allowing us to spread the `prevItems` object into the array. It works with `{ ...product, quantity }` because you are packing the object contents into another object, and adding the `quantity` field. Depending on how you wanted `prevItems` to appear in the JSON perhaps you dont need any spreading at all. In the end doing `[{...(prevItems==null? {}:prevItems )}, {newStuff}]` (wrapped in new {}), would be the same is just including prevItems, be it null or an actual object. '[prevItems, {newStuff}]'.

Comment: Thanks again, as you stated i have applied the code, but it always returning 2 object(console log above) [{object0},{object1}] even if we get another object, i was looking to achieve something like [{object0},{object1},{object2},{object3} and so on...] i mean whenever there is an object received it will add it as an another object

Comment: I see, I had not seen the comment in the code. So you need `prevItems` to be an array of objects. So first, in the ternary operator change the {} to be [], you want to spread an empty array in case prevItems is null, not an object. That should fix the prevItems being null case. Next you want to make sure `prevItems` being passed in is an array. Try printing `typeof` on it. Another potential issue is that `localStorage.getItem` returns a string. You need to convert that to an array before using it as the initial value of state.

Comment: Actually then it might just be able to be fixed like this: `let initialvalue = () => { return JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("user-basket") || "[]");  };`. Here you either get the string representing an array of objects in local storage and you parse it, or you get an empty array. Then you would not need the null check later on since the initial value will at least be the empty array.

Comment: Thanks. now it is resolved(i have updated the code above),  i did as you said but just a bit change as if i dont spread the preItem then it was creating new object in array but also another dimension every time in array[0] location, so i am just checking if it is null i.e first time anything enters that i put as a simple object itself and later on as spreading the objects. Thanks alot  mate :)

Comment: i havent tried it but i think you were write about checking `typeof` of  `prevItems ` and it was first coming as object even though we define as [] in initialvalue, i think the other possible solution to change `previtem` null object into arrray before spreading out and in that case i dont have to use if else check.